# подключение скрипта дл всех пользователей при входе в систему

Tags: linux, bash, centos

как сделать так, чтобы скрипт с автодополнением команды подключался ко всем пользователям при входе в систему, скрипт написан и сохранён в файле, и подключить его надо в таком виде, работаю на CentOS

Comment: Что значит подключался? Был доступен? — тогда поместите куда-нибудь типа `/usr/local/bin`. Автовыполнялся? — https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Autostarting.

Answer (score 1):

`man bash`:

> When  bash  is  invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.

В большинстве современных линуксов `/etc/profile` загружает скрипты из `/etc/profile.d/`.  Добавьте ваш скрипт туда, и он будет загружен для всех пользователей, которые пользуются `bash`.

Например, так загружается автодополнение `bash` для различных известных команд в Ubuntu из файла `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh`